# Is there a holomorphic function on open unit disc with this property?

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $D=\{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid |z|<1\}$. Is there a holomorphic function $f:D\to \mathbb{C}$ such that for every $n\in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\},\;f^{(n)}$ has a continuous extension to $\bar D$ but $f$ has no a holomorphic extension to any open neighborhood of $\bar D$?

Comment: Intuitively, you can construct such a function by using the Szegő kernel and any nonanalytic periodic function of period $=2\pi$.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri  Thank you  very much  for your  comment.

Comment: you’re welcome.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, for example
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\log^2n}z^{n^2}.$$
The radius of convergence is $1$ by Hadamard's test. The function has gaps (the density of the sequence $n^2$ among the integers is zero) which are sufficient to
apply Fabry's gap theorem (or Polya's gap theorem) to ensure that this $f$ does not have any analytic continuation to a larger region than the unit disk,
and all derivatives are continuous in the closed disk because their power series are absolutely and uniformly convergent
in the closed disk.

Refs. It is difficult to find a good exposition of Fabry's work in English,
one can read his original papers (in French) or the exposition of Bieberbach (in his book Analytische Fortsetzung, in German). Polya work is also in German. But for the Polya gap theorem
one can consult Koosis, The Logarithmic integral, vol. II.

Comment: If you use $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n\log n}z^{2^n}$ it should still have the properties required since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {e^{-n\log n}2^{kn}} < \infty$ for all $k \ge 0$ and $({e^{-n\log n}})^{\frac{1}{2^n}} \to 1$ and now the easier Hadamard gap theorem which appears in many complex analysis (and related subjects) texts applies

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko  Prof. Eremenko, Thank you  very  much for  your very interesting answer.

Comment: To  be  honest a  pre  motivation   for  this  question was the  following:  i  was thinking to  a  complete classification of  all sub banach  space (or sub banach  algebra) of  the  disc algebra $\mathcal{A}(\mathbb{D})$  which  are invariants  under the  derivation operator. Further more a  characterization of those subspace(subalgebra) for wich the  differentiation is  a  bounded operator. So this  question leads me  to this  post. Any  way  I  realized that there is  no  a  subalgebra for  which the  differentiation is bounded. because i  remember i heared from some one that the  only

Comment: bounded derivations (in almost all Banach algebras)  are inner. So in the  commutative case we get zero operator. I try  to ask  this  question in a  new post. Thanks  again for  your  answer  and  your  attention to my  question.