# Sub Banach spaces (Banach algebras) of the disc algebra which are invariant under the differentiation operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, operator-theory, banach-algebras

In this question the disc algebra  $\mathcal{A}(\mathbb{D})$ is  the  Banach  algebra  of  all holomorphic  functions  on the unit  open  disc $\mathbb{D} \subset \mathbb{C}$ which  have  a  continuous  extension to the closure $\bar{D}$ of the open disc.

> **Questions:** Is there a  complete classification of  all Banach  subspace of the  disc algebra $\mathcal{A}(\mathbb{D})$ which are invariants  under the  differentiation operator?
>   Is there  a  complete classification of  such  Banach subspace for  which  the  differentiation operator  is  a bounded operator?
>
> Is there a  complete classification of  all  Banach  sub algebra  of  $\mathcal{A}(\mathbb{D})$ which are invariant under the  differentiation operator?

Having these questions in my mind, I  arrived at this  question:

[Is there a holomorphic function on open unit disc with this property?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328289/is-there-a-holomorphic-function-on-open-unit-disc-with-this-property)

Comment: When you say "Banach subspace" do you simply mean a closed subspace of ${\mathcal A}({\mathbb D})$? I think you will have problems finding infinite-dimensional examples, simply because differentiation increases the supremum norm.

Comment: this book may be of interest https://archive.org/details/banachspacesofan032699mbp

Comment: @PietroMajer  Many thanks for this refetence.

Comment: @YemonChoi thanks for your comment. I guess you mean having difficulty to find infinite dimensional space for which d/dz is bounded operator, yes?

Comment: @PietroMajer I'm not sure Hoffman's book will help that much: my recollection is that its main focus is on Hardy spaces (including $H^\infty$ to be fair). But perhaps there is something there which enables progress on Ali's question

Comment: @AliTaghavi I mean that you will have problems defining d/dz on all of your Banach space, even before you seek to show boundedness. Recall that $d/dz$ is only densely-defined as an operator from  ${\mathcal A}({\mathbb D})$ to itself. One again: could you please clarify what you mean by "Banach subspace" in this context?

Comment: @YemonChoi  by Banach subspace, as you pointed out, I mean a closed subvector space.